# What feature selection method should I use for panel data?

Tags: feature-selection, panel-data

I want to implement a multiperiod logit model, so I have panel data. What method should I use for feature selection?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you have to do any feature selection?

Comment: Efficient in what sense? “Efficiency” has a technical meaning in statistics that you might not mean.

Comment: Do you have (too) many variables relative to the number of data samples? In this case your model is likely (or even guaranteed) to overfit. One possible workaround is a penalized regression, but AFAIK there are readily usable software implementations only for particular types of models. A model agnostic approach would be a feature scaling method like using only the first k principal components, linear discriminat analysis, or mutli-dimensional scaling methods.